# In argparse is there a way to finish the first argument entry and start the application over

Tags: python, terminal

Perhaps this is an application question vs specifically the usage of argparse.  However, I was wondering if there was a way when running the python application, with arguments, that when that particular portion of the application is finished if there could be a reprompt of the application again with new arguments for a different argument choice?

Comment: Why edit python from the title?

Comment: Because it's in the tags, that's what they're for.

Comment: What do you mean by "reprompt of the application again"? What prompt? Argparse and etc don't prompt the user, you just type the args in the command line. I don't see what's different from what you want to do, vs just running the script multiple times with different args in terminal. Can you be more explicit on what you want to happen?

Comment: say I have 3 formulas and I want to use the 1st formula.  yes I could at the end of it all reenter the file and terminal argument for the 2nd formula but i'd rather have something that doesn't end and asks me would you like to choose another argument i.e. 2 or 3 or even 1 again

Comment: I'm still confused, argparse does not prompt you so how can it reprompt you? What is the original prompt that you want reprompted?

Comment: i'm using the word prompt but I mean provided argument for a certain portion or aspect of the code so if I say would you like to use 1, 2, or 3

Comment: A script could use `input` to get a string. If convenient it could be split, and the list parsed with argparse just as though it been be entered on a commandline. `parse_args(alist)`

Answer (score 0):

Call `args = parser.parse_args()` again by providing it required input variables?

```
>>> parser.parse_args(['--sum', '7', '-1', '42'])
Namespace(accumulate=<built-in function sum>, integers=[7, -1, 42])
```

Comment: will the Namespace() method reprompt everything again?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew no, you will have to ask the user to input something and gather it with `input()`. Then you can split on spaces and send it into `parse_args()`.

Comment: @alkasm can I just post my code in the python room i think it would be much easier to explain